# Getting trailing zero in csv file for 15 digit number

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I am having a column in csv with 15 digits with value 1234567812345678 but it always coverts the last digit with zero 1234567812345670. I have formatted them as number.

Comment: Are you opening the CSV file in Excel directly? The preferred method is to use "Get External Data"

Comment: yes I am using microsoft excel directly.

Comment: So try using `Get External Data` -> `From Text` instead. It's on the `Data` tab. Select `Text` for `Column Data Format`

Comment: I tried to store as Text wont work. A zero is still trailing

Comment: It works for me, just tested it. Again, you need to use Get External Data. Are you doing that?

Comment: Yes I went to Get External Data -> From Text and it open a file Dialog box to select a Text file. I dont have a text file.

Comment: Also when I set the cell format to text it work and when I close and open the file. the leading zeros come back.

Comment: See the answer I just posted

Comment: just put an apostrophe before the value to make it text `'012345678901234567890`. Don't format as text. [How to stop Excel from formating the 16 digit account number in a way to avoid making the last digit zero?](http://superuser.com/q/634565/241386)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc according to RFC4180 the right way to avoid such issues in CSV is to "enclosing them in double quotes (Hex 22)"

Comment: @Alex I mean in Excel. Didn't notice the csv file at first

Answer (score 3):

As Sir Adelaide answered, Excel supports number precision only up to 15 digits. But you can still save numbers with *many more* digits if you store it as text.

When you open a CSV file in Excel directly, Excel will automatically convert your numbers to number format, causing the truncation. Use `Get External Data` to bypass this:

In a new Excel file, go to the `Data` tab, and click `From Text` in the `Get External Data` section. Navigate to your CSV file and hit `Open`.

Now choose `Delimited`, check `My data has headers` if it does, hit `Next`.

On the next screen, assuming your delimiter is a comma as it is a CSV, make sure only `Comma` is checked and hit `Next`

This is the crucial step: Select the column(s) in the `Data Preview` section with the long numbers and choose `Text`:
[image]

Then just hit `Finish`, select where you want to put your data, and you're done!

Comment: But this will create new file and needs to be saved as excel sheet not csv. I want to save it as csv. If I save it as csv the number are back converted to trailing zeros.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I can save the file from Excel as a CSV and it keeps the full numbers just fine. What are you trying to do exactly? Can you provide a screenshot of how the CSV file looks? Just make sure to replace the CC info with dummy data...

Answer (score 2):

You've run into the maximum precision that Excel can handle (15 digits). See

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#ID0EBABAAA=Excel_2010

for more detail.

Comment: so whats the solution

Comment: @maxspan honestly, use smalller numbers.

Comment: I want to add credit card numbers mate

Comment: try http://superuser.com/questions/373997/adding-more-than-15-digits-in-excel

Comment: If you store it as text as I said in my comment above on OP's question, you can go way beyond 15 digits...and if they're CC #s then I assume no calculation is needed

Comment: or, for credit cards, store the 3 parts of the number in different cells

Comment: @maxspan So drop Excel and use something else if you must store a number with more than 15 digits

Comment: @maxspan Storing CC numbers in an excel spreadsheet is likely to be against the data protection rules in a lot of places ...

Answer (score 1):

Excel seeing you number as a number, just enclose this long number in double quotes (like:"1234567812345678") and it would be treated as a text, so you can keep there even longer numbers for credit cards that may be will appear in a future.

Example:

```
name,card_number,expiration_date
John,"1234567812345678","2017-03-03"
```

Another way to get Excel tricked is to represent card number separated with dashes as 1234-5678-1234-5678 that will be treated by Excel as text too